# Does uTorrent use LAN networking if a peer is on my LAN?

Tags: lan, bittorrent, utorrent

Can uTorrent (or any other bittorrent client for that matter) detect that a peer is on your LAN, and share parts through LAN instead of the internet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does if you enable the right option in the settings:
[image]

You'll also have to unset the `Private` flag for the torrent you want to share locally. According to the help:

> Enable Local Peer Discovery allows µTorrent to attempt to discover
>   local peers via multicast. If a peer is considered local, transfer
>   rates with the peer will not be limited unless Limit local peer
>   bandwidth is also enabled. Local Peer Discovery will not be used for
>   .torrent files with the 'private' flag set. This option serves as a
>   default setting for newly-added torrent jobs, and does not
>   retroactively affect previously-added. This option can be disabled on
>   a per torrent job basis in the respective torrent job's Properties
>   dialog.

Comment: If you unset the Private flag, the info-hash will change and you can no longer participate in the swarm outside the LAN.